# I have two computers with 2 different keyboard languages. Windows 10 keeps mixing them up. How do I change this?

Tags: windows, keyboard, language

**Multiple keyboard issues on 2 PCs w/ windows 10 and same user account**

Basically, I have two different PC's (one is a desktop and one a laptop) with windows 10 set up on each and I use the SAME user account on both PC's linked to my Microsoft account.

The laptop has a UK style keyboard while the desktop has a Croatian keyboard (I bought it while I was posted there and use the desktop so rarely that I have never purchased a UK/international keyboard).

Anyway, when I set up the desktop to use the Croatian keyboard and then log onto the laptop I have the language bar notification icon (keyboard input change icon) appear in the taskbar, and the keyboard automatically gets set to Croatian. Inversely, when I change the laptop keyboard to English and shut down, the desktop PC seems to be set to the English language when I boot it up.

The first time this happened was a real pain to sort since my windows password at the time contained a y (or z, don't remember which) and these keys are inverted on the Croatian keyboard, so I couldn't log onto the system.

Does anyone know how to set up one keyboard on the desktop and one on the laptop without having them link this way through the user account?

p.s. I have NEVER set up a Croatian keyboard on the laptop since I don't know the language well enough for it to be useful and when I remove the keyboard from either PC it gets removed from both.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your settings are synchronized to all your devices because you log onto them with the same Microsoft account. To change this specific setting, open the Settings app and navigate to *Accounts* → *Sync your settings* (on the left). You can then disable the *Language preferences* slider. That will stop the syncing of keyboard layouts, display languages, and date/time formats.

Comment: will do. I've been searching for a solution online for ages and couldn't find what was happening. Thanks for sorting it out so quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You may set the keyboard layout by group policy. Please refer to this [TechNet Article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/6281.how-to-set-the-keyboard-layout-through-group-policy-gpo.aspx). This should override any user specific setting.

Create an `.adm` file with these contents:

```
CLASS USER
  CATEGORY "Keyboard Layout"
     POLICY "Keyboard layout"
     KEYNAME "Keyboard Layout\Preload"
         PART "Enable English" CHECKBOX
           DEFCHECKED
          VALUENAME "1"
           VALUEON "00000409"
           VALUEOFF DELETE
         END PART
     END POLICY

  END CATEGORY
```

Comment: Note that the Home edition of Windows does not have the Group Policy editor. Also, please include the relevant parts of the article in your answer in case the link breaks.